# Checkbox disabled not returning result from stored checkbox array

Tags: jquery

I am storing all checkboxes what my div has in to a variable, later i am finding disabled from the stored variable, but i am not get proper result, instead if  I find separately I am getting proper result..

what why i am not find the disabled from my stored variable?

here is my code:

```
  var   checkedBoxes = $(".locale-container .panel ul li").find("input:checkbox"),
            disabledBoxes = checkedBoxes.find("input:checkbox:disabled"); // not getting
```

But "disabledBoxes" not getting result from checkBoxes.

In case if I do like this:

```
 var    checkedBoxes = $(".locale-container .panel ul li").find("input:checkbox"),
            disabledBoxes = $(".locale-container .panel ul li").find("input:checkbox:disabled"); // it works
```

so how can i filter or get the appropriate checkboxes from stored variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery 1.9.1, currently i am using.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this way:

```
var $parent = $(".locale-container .panel ul li"),
    checkboxes = $parent.find("input:checkbox"),
    disabledBoxes = $parent.find("input:checkbox:disabled"); // NOW YOU GET IT
```

Try this and see if it solves the issue.

You were not getting the disabled checkboxes because of the context of the selector:

here:

```
$(".locale-container .panel ul li").find("input:checkbox")
```

You have got the checkboxes in this "`var checkedBoxes`" and you were trying to see disabled in this context, means you were checking if checkboxes has disabled checkboxes.

Solution is:

Take a parent then find the input type checkboxes as required.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the disabled attribute.
You could achive this using [**has attribute selector**](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) in jQuery.

```
var disabledBoxes = $(".locale-container .panel ul li")
                     .find("input:checkbox[disabled]")
```

or with **[has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**

```
   checkedBoxes.has("[disabled]")
```